# Remember the date after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

*Edited*

I am making a forum and it has a deadline date option.
I want to remember the date after the page refreshes.

here is a small part of the code

What I want to accomplish is that if date is entered but name is not entered in the input field and submit is pressed then when the page reloads it should still remember the date that was entered

**CODE**

```
 <?php 
$edate_error = $name_error =  $failure="";
$edate =$name = $success="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["edate"])){
  $edate_error = "* Deadline date is required";
 }
 if (empty($_POST["name"])){
  $name_error = "* Name is required";
 }


 if ($edate_error=='' && $name_error==''){

    $edate = $name = $success = "";

    $success = 'Success';
 }

else {
  $failure = 'Error';
}
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<span>
    <div><?= $success ?></div>
    <div><?= $failure ?></div>
</span>
<form method="POST" action="<?php htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" >
    <h2>Please enter deadline</h2>
    <input name="edate" type="date" <?php isset($_POST['edate']) ? $_POST['edate'] : "";?>" >
    <br><span><?= $edate_error ?></span>

    <h2>Please enter name</h2>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="<?= $name ?>">
    <br><span><?= $name_error ?></span>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use sessions for this.

Comment: Is your form actually POSTing or is it GETting? can you post your `<form>` element?

Comment: If this is for a single user (not all users) you could use local storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: The first example will fail as it omits the `value=""` part of the HTML, just drops in the `$_POST` var - the 2nd version will fail if you've not assigned `$edate` from `$_POST['edate']`

Comment: It is POSTing the data to mysql and I have a validation code that refreshes the page on submit to validate the data. every thing is remembered when page is refreshed and an error prompt occurs but the date is not remembered

Comment: If all of that ^ is going on, then you should really show more code than you currently are.

Comment: add your html form. that will give more insight on the problem.

Comment: I have edited my code kindly review it @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: You still don't have a `value` attribute on your `edate` field.  See how you're doing it on the `name` field?  You need the same thing.  Also, for the instances where you use the full `<?php` tags, you need to `echo` the value that you want displayed.  Personally, I recommend _always_ using the full tags.

Comment: thank you so much it worked